# can not build a C++ project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded this C++ project from this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice

And then try to compile it using Visual Studio 2010, I got some problems:

```
Error   3   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000F) "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@$$FYAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Managed_Wrapper::Managed_Wrapper_Class::Managed_Wrapper_Class(void)" (??0Managed_Wrapper_Class@Managed_Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)  C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Managed_Wrapper.obj  Managed_Wrapper
Error   4   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000010) "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@$$FYAPAXI@Z) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Managed_Wrapper::Managed_Wrapper_Class::Managed_Wrapper_Class(void)" (??0Managed_Wrapper_Class@Managed_Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ) C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Managed_Wrapper.obj  Managed_Wrapper
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Stdafx.obj   Managed_Wrapper
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Unmanaged.obj    Managed_Wrapper
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Unmanaged.obj    Managed_Wrapper
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\AssemblyInfo.obj Managed_Wrapper
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\AssemblyInfo.obj Managed_Wrapper
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Managed_Wrapper.obj  Managed_Wrapper
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Managed_Wrapper.obj  Managed_Wrapper
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@$$FYAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Managed_Wrapper::Managed_Wrapper_Class::Managed_Wrapper_Class(void)" (??0Managed_Wrapper_Class@Managed_Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Managed_Wrapper.obj  Managed_Wrapper
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@$$FYAPAXI@Z) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Managed_Wrapper::Managed_Wrapper_Class::Managed_Wrapper_Class(void)" (??0Managed_Wrapper_Class@Managed_Wrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)  C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\Managed_Wrapper.obj  Managed_Wrapper
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CorDllMain@12   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_Wrapper\LINK Managed_Wrapper
Error   15  error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals   C:\Users\310052290\Desktop\DemoProject\Managed_VBdotNET\Release\Managed_Wrapper.dll Managed_Wrapper
```

How can I fix the problems of compiling the C++ project in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added these libraries in the "additional dependencies" kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib

Comment: I am working with all solutions using VS2010. I can not get rid of VS2010.

Comment: If you look @ the comments it seems this does not build correctly under vs2k5+

Comment: @iKiar DevC++ is [the very worst of alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info) you could have mentioned. And there is really no reason to hate Visual Studio.

Comment: Operators `new` and `delete` are part of the C++ standard library. Make sure you link against that!

Answer (score 4):

You should remove `/Zl` from `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `All Options` -> `Additional Options`